# Vertical sliding / toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, toggle, slidetoggle

I'd like to use the vertical sliding/toggle menu, please see my code below, at the moment the menu toggles only when you click on the + sign, please see the code below.

I'm trying to work out a way when you click on the category name eg Posts and the sub menu would open (same functionality with the +) and the page would go to Posts page. And when you click on the + sign, the function and the page stay the same.

How can I target this task? Your help / suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{background:#CCC;}
#container{margin:0 auto; background:white; border:1px solid #999; width:400px;       padding:20px; -moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;  overflow:hidden;}
#menu {text-align:left;}
/*Toggle Area*/
#menu .toggle {float:right;width:9px; padding:5px; cursor:pointer; border-top:1px     solid white; border-left:1px solid #E0E0E0; color:#999;}
#menu ul.navmenu li:first-child .toggle{border-width:0 0 0 1px;}
/*Menu Setup*/
#menu ul{padding:0; margin:0; width:150px;}
#menu ul ul{border:1px solid #CCC;overflow:hidden;}
#menu ul.navmenu li {margin:0; list-style:none;float:left;}
#menu ul.navmenu li li {float:none;}
/*Links*/
#menu ul.navmenu a, #menu ul.navmenu a:visited {text-decoration:none; padding:5px; display:block; color:#008FDD;}
#menu ul.navmenu ul.submenu a:hover{background:#FFF4D2; color:#333;}
/*Heading Outer div*/
#menu ul.navmenu .menutop{border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:0 1px; overflow:hidden; width:150px; background:#F9F9F9; }
/*Header Links*/
#menu ul.navmenu .menutop a{width:120px;float:left;margin:0 0 1px 0; border-top:1px solid white;}
/*Header Link Hover*/
 #menu ul.navmenu .menutop a:hover{color:#333;}
/*Removes white border for the first header*/
 #menu ul.navmenu li:first-child .menutop a {border-width:0px;}
/*Single Menu Width Fix*/
#menu ul.navmenu .menusingle a{width:140px;}
/*Border Radius and Special Border Width*/
#menu ul.navmenu li:first-child .menutop{border-width:1px 1px 0 1px; -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;}
#menu ul.navmenu li:last-child .menutop{border-width:0px 1px 1px 1px; -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;}
 #menu ul.navmenu li:last-child ul.submenu{-moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;}
#menu ul.navmenu li:last-child .menutop-open{-moz-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-radius:0px; border-width:0 1px;} 
</style>
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"   type="text/javascript">

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
hideMenus();

$('.toggle').click(function(){
    var menu = $(this);
    hideMenus();

    if (menu.hasClass('toggle-open')) {     
        menuHide(menu);
    }else{
        menuShow(menu);
    }
});
});
 function hideMenus(){
$('.toggle').each(function(){
    menuHide($(this));
});
}

function menuHide(menu){ 
menu.removeClass('toggle-open').addClass('toggle-closed').empty('').append('+').parents('li').children('ul').slideUp(250); 
menu.parent('.menutop').removeClass('menutop-open').addClass('menutop-closed'); 
} 
function menuShow(menu){ 
menu.parent('.menutop').removeClass('menutop-closed').addClass('menutop-open'); 
menu.removeClass('toggle-closed').addClass('toggle-open').empty('').append('–').parents('li').children('ul').slideDown(250); 
}



</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
<ul class="navmenu">
<li><div class="menutop"><a href="#">Posts</a><div class="toggle">+</div></div>
 <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Tags</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><div class="menutop"><a href="#">Pages</a><div class="toggle">+</div></div>
 <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><div class="menutop menusingle"><a href="#">Comments</a></div></li>
<li><div class="menutop"><a href="#">Users</a><div class="toggle">+</div></div>
 <ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to click the category name instead of + ?

Comment: The `toggle` class appears to be what is used to select the element that toggles the submenu.

Comment: Hi JQuerybeast, thanks for your fast replay. I'd like to click on the name as well as the + sign. So when you click on category name, it going to the category name page and slide the following menu down. When you click on the + sign only, the following menu goes down but the page remains on the same page. i hope this makes sense.Thank you. S:)

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for your reply. Any code/suggestions on how I target this toggle class? Thanks very much, S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code I have used to do exactly that, except I used arrow images instead of + and - but you should be able to modify it. Hope it helps!

**Edit:**
I've put the code below onto JSFiddle so you can try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/CrxAg/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="submenublock" id="submenu1"><h3>Category1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page.html">option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">option2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    <div class="submenublock" id="submenu2"><h3>Category2</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page.html">option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">option2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.submenublock > ul').hide();  
    $("div.submenublock > h3").css("background", "url(images/menuarrowdown.gif) no-repeat right bottom");

    $('div.submenublock > h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast',function(){
            //set arrow depending on whether menu is shown or hidden
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).prev().css("background", "url(images/menuarrowdown.gif) no-repeat right bottom"); 
            } else {
                $(this).prev().css("background", "url(images/menuarrowup.gif) no-repeat right bottom"); 
            }
            return false;
        }); 
   });

    /* change appearance of h3 element on hover to make it look like a link */
    $('div.submenublock > h3').hover(over, out);
    function over(event) {
        $(this).find("a").css("color", "#663");
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    }
    function out(event) {
        $(this).find("a").css("color", "");
        $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    } 
    /*end hover code*/
});
```

Comment: Hi Fluffykitten, thanks very much for the edit. I will give it a try and let you know how I go. Thanks very much for your reply. S:)

Comment: No prob. Just to let you know I'd the wrong link for JSFiddle in case you have tried it already, I've updated it with the correct one now (http://jsfiddle.net/CrxAg/3/)

Comment: I noticed you edited your post to include your code, so I've got it working with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/MCLFt/1/   Its not exactly what you need - it doesn't close the other categories when you open one. Also the border on the last menu is a bit off, it may be to do with the ids I gave to each menu, but you'll know your css better than anyone.

Comment: Hi Kitten, I edited my post and run away from the question. I've tried the submenublock code you gave to me just now, hooray it works wonderfully, thanks. It's better than the tutorial one I got. Just one question, I don't know how easy this can be done. I put a link for the category name eg category 1 (which is h3), when people click on category 1 it goes to the page, is it possible to make the <a> tag extends until the arrow image, at the mo the blank between category 1 and arrow just extends the menu. Any suggestions? Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Hi Kitten, thanks very much for your help and follow up, so nice of you for what you've done for me! I'll accept your answer for sure, I just got a question re your edit2, I've tried your code but it turns the category name &arrow image into a link and it doesn't do the menu sliding anymore. I'm using your http://jsfiddle.net/CrxAg/3/ code, &I've altered it to be like the side bar of http://www.anz.com/personal/bank-accounts/ but stuck on making the blank part between the category name and arrow image. Is it possible to make the blank part to be the same link as category name? Thank you. :)

Comment: In fact if it is too complicated to make the gap between the category name and arrow image as a page link, don't worry. The way your menu - http://jsfiddle.net/CrxAg/3/ works is great. I'm stoked by the help you've given me. It's great to see there are some nice great developers like you, I hope one day I can help others like you do. Thank you very much Fluffykitten, very cool/cute name. Have a great week. Thanks heaps! S:)

Comment: Thanks Sam! Sorry, I just realised what I gave you is totally wrong for what you asked... it works in cases where the menu doesn't have a submenu. What is the structure of your Category heading at the moment? If you use a background image for the arrow on the h3 tag then the code should work as it was, but as its not then I presume you've another div or something. Can you tell me what you have now for the category block, e.g. <div class="submenublock" id="submenu2"><h3>Category 2</h3>

Comment: Just saw your 2nd comment... no its not difficult at all to make the full block a link, basically you just need to call the click function on the containing element instead of the h3 but if you show me the structure I'll be able to explain better. And its my pleasure to be able to help!

Comment: Thanks very much Kitten, this is the html code in the productmenu div <div class="submenublock" id="submenu1"><h3><a href="#">Category 1</a></h3> <ul class="second_level"><li><a href="page.html">Option 1</a></li><li><a href="page.html">Option 2</a></li> </ul> </div> and repeat it for the whole menu. I did some css style to match the look for http://www.anz.com/personal/bank-accounts/ and I'm using your JS from http://jsfiddle.net/CrxAg/3/ Thanks very very much. I have to leave the forum now, but will be back first thing tomorrow. Thanks heaps!!!!:)

Comment: Hmmm... I can't see why that won't work.Would you be able to add the  html, js and css for the menu into jsfiddle.net so I can see it all in action? It'd be easier to spot the problem that way! Talk tomorrow :-)

Comment: Hi Kitten, I just uploaded your great menu onto the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VEg5e/, you can see only category names are the links. Just to clarify what I'm trying to achieve, I'd like the category names and the gap till the arrow image to be the page link as well as doing the sliding menu, and the arrow image will be working the same. Example see sidebar: http://www.anz.com/personal/bank-accounts/ Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks very very much for your wonderful help, I really appreciate! :)

Comment: Actually it already works like that! Its just that the cursor doesn't change on mouse-over because its a h3 element and not an a element. I've edited my post to include js code to change the appearance of the h3 and make it look like a link and you can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/VEg5e/3/

Comment: Alternatively for this example, you can do it just with CSS! If you  add display:block; to the submenublock a, it will allow the clickable area grow to the constraints of the containing h3 element. See that here: http://jsfiddle.net/VEg5e/4/ It would work better if you move the padding from the h3 to the h3 a instead. This works in this example, but won't work in every situation if the a elements are not able to expand to the full size of the h3 block.

Comment: Thanks Kitten, I'll let you go very soon, I know what you helped me is more than enough. Re your jsfiddle.net/VEg5e/3, I understand the colour is changed but the gap is still not a link as the category name, is it poss to make the gap a link too? The /*added this*/ part $(this).css({'color' : '#666633', "cursor", "pointer"}); came up a syntax error. Thanks heaps!

Comment: The gap is working for me... strange. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/VEg5e/9/ I've changed the css to make it easier to see whats happening. I've added a red border around the h3, and if I click anywhere within that box, it expands the menu. I make the background an attractive shade of yellow :) once it is a link. What does it do for you? I've removed the code that had the "add this" comment - it was commented out and didn't work (as you discovered!). The code you need is at the end - I've added a comment to make it more obvious.

Comment: I must be confusing you, sorry. This is what I've seen: The js code you added is changing the colour of the whole category names space to yellow when hovering, but the yellow is not a link - in this case <a href="#">. Cos the link # only shows up at the bottom of the left hand corner when I hover over the category names but no link shows up in the corner when I hover on the yellow. Is it poss to make the yellow as the same link (#) as category names? I hope that makes sense.Thank you! :)

Comment: OK I am a bit confused! If you click on the yellow outside the category name, does it not activate the link & expand the menu? By default only a elements act like links, so we have to code this functionality for any other elements such as the h3. In other words, a h3 element doesn't normally change colour, status or cursor so we have to tell it to. In our code we only tell it to change the colour & cursor on mouse-over, we didn't tell it to change the status. But that doesn't mean its not a link, it still acts like a link because we told it to do so in the click function. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Kitten, when I click on the yellow outside the category name, it expands the menu but not active the link. I think to be able to make the yellow an active link but not the arrow image, I may have to change the whole page structure, so I'd better stick to your original code. Thanks very much for all your detailed explanations, follow ups and help. You have been super great to me, I can't say enough thank you to you. FluffyKitten rocks! thanks! :)

Comment: Ohhh... I was going to say there is no link, but do you plan on making the text "category 1" link to a page but have outside that expand the menu? If so - sorry I did misunderstand! So you only want the arrow to expand but the rest of the box to go to a page? Yes thats possible too... let me know if thats what you need and I can do it quickly!

Comment: Guys, this is getting too long. Please consider moving to an SO chat room!

Comment: @SamIAm, have a look at this & see if its what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/VEg5e/12/ Good luck with it! 
If you need me, I'll be in the javascript chatroom for the next 30 min or so: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript  I've never used it before so um... I don't know how you'll find me :-)

Comment: As @markus said, please consider taking extended discussions to [chat]. Thanks.